# How to mitigate Spectre and Meltdown kernel memory leaking CPU bug on OpenBSD?

Tags: kernel, security, cpu, openbsd, memory-leaks

[Kernel-memory-leaking Intel processor design flaw forces Linux, Windows redesign](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/01/02/intel_cpu_design_flaw/)

and

[Reading privileged memory with a side-channel](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.hu/2018/01/reading-privileged-memory-with-side.html)

In recent news people could read about a kernel memory leaking CPU bug.

If using OpenBSD, how can we defend ourselves? Or OpenBSD isn't affected?

Comment: A quick search I found this: [https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-misc&m=118296441702631&w=2]

Comment: https://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article;sid=20180106082238

Comment: https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-tech&m=151521435721902

Answer (score 4):

CPU microcode update code for amd64

https://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article;sid=20180115073406

https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-tech&m=151588857304763&w=2

> When you **fw_update**, you'll get the firmware files.
>
> Upon a reboot, it will attempt to update the microcode on your cpus.
>   Maybe there isn't a new microcode.  Maybe your BIOS has a copy of the
>   microcode and installs it before booting OpenBSD.
>
> This firmware installation is done a little late.  Doing it better
>   will require some work in the bootblocks to find the firmware files,
>   but time is a bit short to do that right now.
>
> The branch-target-cache flushing features added in new microcode are
>   not being used yet.  There is more code which has to be written, but
>   again other work is happening first.
>
> Also, Intel is saying their new microcodes sucks and people should
>   wait a little.
>
> "Hi, my name is Intel and I'm an cheating speculator".

**So the current status**: do a "fw_update" command as root and reboot.